# Password recovery URL has error - but not found in code or db

Tags: login, password

On a multisite/network install, all of a sudden my password recovery URL has a problem:

```
 http//my.domain.com/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword
```

Note the lack of a colon following the 'http'.

A grep of the database and codebase does not reveal any culprits (although it must be in there somewhere). Any idea what might cause the problem? The site domain settings all seem correct.

Here's the multisite config:

```
/* Multisite */
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'http://my.networkdomain.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define( 'SUNRISE', 'on' );
```

Comment: You can recover your password using phpmyadmin

Comment: Sorry Farzad, that's not the problem. My general users cannot recover their passwords by that method, and they are getting sent to a broken URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was in the multisite settings in the `wp_site` table.

The `domain` field entry was set (probably manually during a change of domain names) to `"http://my.domain.com"`. It should not have included the protocol, but just be a bare domain.

Wordpress adds another `"http://"` to the start of the domain, and then runs it through a text filter, which strips out the second `":"`. What I ended up with was `"http://http//my.domain.com"`

As a result I could not use grep to find the 'typo' in the code of database as it was generated on the fly.

A simple fix, but a tough one to track down.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the home url for your site is being overridden in your wp-config.php file, I would make sure the missing colon isn't originating from there.

Comment: I don't think so. I'm going to copy the Multisite config into the OP